# Android: cursor.close() when using registerContentObserver

Tags: android, cursor, contentobserver

Do i have to close a cursor when using

```
 startManagingCursor(cursor); //I know its deprecated
```

and

```
cursor.registerContentObserver(..
```

if so, where to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `startManagingCursor` you do not need to close the cursor, Activity will take care of that for you.

But if you have called `registerContentObserver` , you need to call `unregisterContentObserver`. Usually you call registerContentObserver  in OnResume and unregisterContentObserver in OnPause, But it can change depending upon what kind of operations you are performing in `ContentObserver`.